# Recovering corrupted Windows 10 user profile

Tags: windows, hard-drive, user-accounts

I had to remove my hard drive from my PC recently, and view the data there. It could not be accessed, with a message "you don't currently have permission to access this folder". To fix this, I added a group or username "everyone" to the folder in question.

My PC has been fixed, and I replaced the hard drive. Upon booting up, I was met with the message "we can't sign in to your account". After some research and troubleshooting (including booting with safe mode).

I found the following tutorial:
http://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-youve-been-signed-in-with-a-temporary-profile/

With an administrator account, in regedit, I navigated to the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

There, I located the SID key with a .bak extension, for which the `ProfileImagePath` is C:\Users\Al2110. This appears to be the path to the corrupted user profile. All the data I expect to be there, was there.

According to the tutorial, the profile needs to be rebuilt. This would involve deleting the subkey that is the same, but without the .bak extension. In my case, it points to the path C:\Users\TEMP. I don't have any subkey which has the computer name in it. Would doing this delete all my data?

Comment: The only easy way to fix this is by first making sure you have a profile that works (create a new user if you have to) then use a tool such as Profile Wizard, to migrate the data and settings from your old profile into the new one. (https://www.forensit.com/downloads.html)

Comment: @LPChip I created an Administrator account with the cmd `net user administrator /active:yes` will that suffice?

Comment: Administrator is a special account name. You really do not want to use Administrator as account name. Anything else will suffice.